# Leading character on hex number (x0)

Tags: math, computer-science, decimal, hex

I've googled this but possibly typing in the wrong thing.

I see hexadecimal numbers knocking about such as 3A and 0x3A, but what does the leading 0x mean?  I read somewhere it means the number is signed, but converting a negative decimal to hex in calc doesn't produce a hexadecimal number with the leading 0x.

Any points much appreicated.

Comment: There as 10 kinds of people in this world: those who understand binary and those who don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a convention, used in C and C-like languages, to distinguish between different bases, e.g. `0x10` (hex) versus `10` (decimal) versus `010` (octal) versus `0b10` (binary).

Answer (score 1):

It's just a convention that means that the number is in hexadecimal notation instead of decimal. It isn't required if it's understood that the number is supposed to be hexadecimal.

Also:

```
>>> -0xe
-14
```

Answer (score 1):

The 0x is just a convention to indicate that the number is in hex. Other ways this is indicated:

1. 3Ah (used in many assembers)
2. &h3A (used in BASICs)
3. (This number is written in hex!) 3A (used... by normal people, I guess)